# Linear Discriminant Analysis in sklearn fail to reduce the features size

Tags: python, scikit-learn

From what I know, Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) is a technique to reduce the number of input features. Wiki also states the same

> Linear discriminant analysis (LDA), normal discriminant analysis (NDA), or discriminant function analysis is a generalization of Fisher's linear discriminant, a method used in statistics, pattern recognition and machine learning to find a linear combination of features that characterizes or separates two or more classes of objects or events. The resulting combination may be used as a linear classifier, or, more commonly, for dimensionality reduction before later classification.

However, when I try to use the `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` from `sklearn.discriminant_analysis`, I failed to get the data with reduced features.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

X, y = make_blobs(40000,600,2,cluster_std=20,random_state=101)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=101)

model = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=100)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

X_train_new = model.transform(X_train)
print(X_train_new.shape)
>>> (28000, 1)
```

My original data has 600 features, I would like to reduce it to only 100 features with the `LDA`. But the `LDA` from `sklearn` gave me the shape (28000,1) instead.

Why is there only 1 feature after the LDA transformation? What am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I think you want to use [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA) in this case. LDA finds attributes that account for the most variance between classes. Therefore, the `n_components` should be less than the number of classes - 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `LDA` transforms your dataset to only one feature because LDA will escape `n_components > (n_classes - 1)`.
Here you have two classes `=> 2 - 1 = 1 feature`.
Please refer to [LDA for two classes on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#LDA_for_two_classes)

Change your number of centers to `200` for example and you'll see the difference

```
Xx, yy = make_blobs(40000, 600, centers=200, cluster_std=5)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xx, yy, test_size=0.3)
model = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=100)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train_new = model.transform(X_train)
print(X_train_new.shape)
>> (28000, 100)
```

Use `PCA` or `SVD` otherwise

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
X_train_new = svd.fit_transform(X_train)
svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum() # should be > 0.90
print(X_train_new.shape)
>>> (28000, 100)
```

Comment: But my real data is a binary classification problem. Is it possible to still reduce the features from 600 to 100? Or is there any literature that restrict the LDA dimension to be always less than the number of classes?

Comment: Please see edit and accept answer if it solves your question :)